# MongoDB fulltext search taking start of the word

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a issue with my MongoDB query, i need to search inside my field and only search from start of the word not 100% match of the words.

before this issue hit me, i use `$regex` and here its no problem, the only problem is its a lots slower then `$text` search, so now i hope one out there can help me.

this is my query today

```
db.getCollection('product').aggregate([
   {$match : {$text: { $search : "\"samsung\" \"evo\" } } },
   {$project: { _id: 0, Category: 1 } },
   {$unwind: "$Category" },
   {$group: { _id: '$Category', count: { $sum: 1 } } },
   {$project: { _id: 0,Category: "$_id", count: 1 } },
   {$sort: { 'count': -1 } },
   {$limit: 5}
])
```

and what i have try as i say i have used $regex before, but here its not use any kind of index and then the query in MongoDB is so slow and everything stuck the differed its like 0.4 sec vs 0.03 sec for each query.

so if there are one out there can explain to me whats happen and how the solution is and why its will help me a lot.

right now the word its "match 100% samsung and evo" what i want are i can type like sam and evo then its find everything there have evo and start with sam its will make the search even faster for the user.

thanks for all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Regex` or regular expressions will always be slower than text searches. Possible solutions to this are:

- When inserting the doc, add another `field` which classifies the document while inserting.(This is more related to database design). This will allow easy search using `text`.
- Switch to `elasticsearch`(This might not be that feasible, depends on the stage of your project)

Comment: How can i use elasticsearch in MongoDB? its sound interesting.

Comment: @ParisNakitaKejser `Elasticsearch` is a search engine document store, you don't use it *in* `MongoDB`. Check this [page](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch). Also this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elasticsearch).